# Как в static методе вызвать другой метод C#?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main()
{
}
```

В методе Main нужно вызвать метод Setup

```
void Setup()
{
}
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: `static void Setup()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 способ (создание приватного метода внутри метода, доступ к которому будет ТОЛЬКО внутри самого метода `Main`)

```
static void Main()
{
    static void Setup()
    {
    }
}
```

2 способ:

```
static void Main()
{
    Setup();
}

static void Setup()
{
}
```

Почему ваш способ не совсем правильный - вы создаёте НОВЫЙ экземпляр класса, новую корзинку, которая занимает место в вашей тележке (памяти). Захотите обратиться снова к этому элементу - новая корзинка? Как-то звучит даже не очень.

Да, у нас есть гарбадж коллектор, который вызывает финалайз у всех элементов, ссылка на которые никуда не ведут, но...зачем?

А теперь представьте, что этот метод возвращает какие-то значения или устанавливает их для свойств в этом классе, которые где-то используются. При реализации, которую вы указали в ответе, вы не сможете получить доступ к этим элементам, потому что создали НОВЫЙ экземпляр класса.

Представьте, что каждый экземпляр (`new(...)`) - новая корзинка с яблоками. Чтобы получить яблоко из корзинки вы не должны создавать новую корзинку. Вы должны обратиться к уже созданной корзинке. С экземплярами класса аналогичная ситуация. Можете дополнить ваш ответ, рассказав, что именно вы хотите сделать - возможно, это поможет решить вашу проблему.

Comment: `внутри самого метода Main` вложенные методы - источник путаницы. Для новичка даже знания о них - сомнительое удовольствие. В создании экземпляра Program вреда не вижу, хотя пользы само собой тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Я создал ссылку на класс в котором находится метод `Setup`
и вызвал его через ссылку

```
var p = new Program();
p.Setup();
```

Всё заработало.

Comment: Зачем заминусовали новичка? Нормальный рабочий способ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На самом деле, такое решение возможно и оно даже будет работать, но нужно понимать, что данный код влечёт под собой. Что-то мне подсказывает, что автор совершенно не понимает, что он делает. Как по мне, ответом на данный вопрос (и на данный ответ в том числе) будет объяснение: что такое экземпляр класса и зачем эта гадость вообще нужна, что такое статика и тд. Может добавите ответ? Думаю, это сможет помочь новичку разобраться в этой теме

Comment: @Frehzy - я считаю, что не стоит новичков сразу же минусовать. Они после этого не могут новые вопросы задавать, система не даёт. Как им тогда ума-разума набираться?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov плюсанул

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Хм, никогда не задумался об этой стороне. Спасибо, что сказали